# How is a change in capacitance detected in a touch-screen?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance

So the screen has lines of conductors horizontally and vertically, seperated by a dielectric, and thus forming a grid of capacitators where the ones in one "row" are in parallell on the one side, and in series on the other (correct?).

Introducing your finger, as a conductor over the screen (dielectric), will somehow change the capacitance of the capacitators in the area of your finger, and this is somehow detected and registered... how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a resistance based touch screen, it uses it's the user's pressure to control the flow of current. But the capacitive touch screens work in a different way. Human body is basically a conductor. It can hold charge. The capacitive touch screens are constructed from copper or indium oxide. They could store electric charge in between tiny wires forming a grid like structure. This can be done by growing tiny grids in a copper piece, which is not a problem in this new era of nanotechnology. When the finger touches the screen, since the human body is grounded, the charges in these tiny capacitors flow through us and complete a circuit. This reduced charge creates a voltage drop at the point of contact on the screen. If you wear cloth like gloves, this process will not take place. This means the capacitive touch screens do not work using insulators. The machine register note down the position where the p.d. occurs and convert it into the necessary action assigned to it.